# How to debug javascript tests on Node.js with Selenium WebDriver by breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I use WebStorm to write my javascript tests. I have include Selenium WebDriver (+ chromedriver) to run my tests in browser. As a test-runner framework I use Mocha.

**The problem is:** when I try to debug my test and set a breakpoint into code, while debugging WebDriver does not starts. And as a result I could not see any variables realtime.

Code example:

```
// Add external libraries
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'), webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;
var mocha = require('./node_modules/mocha/mocha.js'), chai = require('chai'), chaiuse = require('chai-as-promised'), expect = require('chai').expect;
var assert = require('assert');
// global variable for webdriver browser
var browser;
// Main part with test suites
test.describe('Suite 1', function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    test.beforeEach( function(){ // Executes before each test
        browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({ 'browserName' : 'chrome', 'timeout' : '5000' }).build();
    });
    test.afterEach( function(){ // Executes after each test
        browser.close();
    });
    test.it('Get Fields', function(done) {
        browser.get('http://google.com');
        var btnFirst = browser.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.name('btnK'), 30000));
        var btnSecond = browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnI')).getAttribute("name");
        btnSecond.then(function(text) {
            console.log("Name of Second button: " + text + "\n");
            assert.equal(text,'btnI','Button with name \'btnI\' not presented');
        });
        done();
    });
});
```

And so for now all process is like black-box tests development.

I have tried [DevTools](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/debugging-nodejs-in-chrome-devtools) - a chrome console to work. But it just run all test without pause on breakpoints.Command:

```
devtool node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -qc -- ./Tests.js --break
```

On C# + Selenium WebDriver I have no problems with step by step debugging, but now I need to do that on JavaScript + Selenium WebDriver.

Please, give an advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug Mocha tests just like any Node.js script with the help of **node-inspector** :

- Install and run node-inspector:

  `npm install -g node-inspector`
  `node-inspector`
- Run your tests with break option: 
  `mocha [options] --debug-brk`
- Open the debugger in Chrome at url http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858

You can set your breakpoints and enjoy debugging with Chrome Dev Tools!

Source: [How to debug Mocha tests with Chrome](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-debug-mocha-tests-with-chrome/)

Comment: I still could not get elements from 'webdriver'. I have faced with the same behavior as other ways of debugging - webdriver graphically executes all commands after code was debugged. Even though I put breackpoints and successfully stepped my code.

Comment: @Alex.K You could add a `debugger` statement before the line you want the debugger to break, and see if it stops